# CSS rules for almost identical nested selectors

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write simpler responsive css rules for a website, I need to have the following with less repeating text:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper h1 {
     text-align:center !important;
  }
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper h2 {
     text-align:center !important;
  }
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper h3 {
     text-align:center !important;
  }
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper p {
     text-align:center !important;
  }
}
```

What I mean is: Center every heading1, heading2, heading3 and paragraph that are found inside an .wpb_wrapper element which is inside a .centertext element.

I am sure there is a symbol or something simple I have to put between ".centertext .wpb_wrapper" and all those guys (or maybe the space character should go away too?), but I don't know what it is. Please help!

Thanks in advance.
J

Comment: I am sure I can do this:
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper h1, .centertext .wpb_wrapper h2, .centertext .wpb_wrapper h3, .centertext .wpb_wrapper p {
     text-align:center !important;
  }
}

But that's not the point, I think there is something shorter.

Comment: to know how short you can get it, you'd really need to also share the style NOT in the media query...what else is going on that you need to get so specific, and/or use the !important tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to shorten your code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper h1,
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper h2,
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper h3,
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper p{
    text-align:center !important;
  }
}
```

If you wan to apply it to all elements you can use

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .centertext .wpb_wrapper > * {
    text-align:center !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems fine, but I think it would also affect something else, for example ".centertext .wpb_wrapper div".
I don't want the divs to get this rule.

Comment: well then you can use the first part of my answer. I don't think you can reduce it more than that without using any pre-processor and even with one it won't be easy.

You can always use javacript to add another class or inline style when your window is at maximum 767px wide

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the repetition a little bit by [comma-separating the selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Groups_of_selectors_on_one_rule) and declaring the rules a single time:

```css
.centertext .wpb_wrapper h1,
.centertext .wpb_wrapper h2,
.centertext .wpb_wrapper h3,
.centertext .wpb_wrapper p {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

But why not just this?

```css
.centertext {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Why have a class called `centertext` if it doesn't *always* center text?

Comment: Thanks @ray hatfield, that's what I tried first, but ".wpb_wrapper" has some rules that override my centering, that's why I need t to be that specific.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .centertext {text-align:center;}
}
```

If you don't have other rules on your h1/h2/h3 etc overriding that, it will be inherited.  If you have other rules conflicting, you probably can simplify be re-ordering your CSS or making sure the conflicts have similar media query restrictions.

I normally try to avoid !important unless there's no way around it. Usually that's only true if you don't have control over all the code that's impacting the site.

Comment: Thanks @ryantdecker, that's what I tried first, but, as you mention, ".wpb_wrapper" has some rules that override my centering, that's why I need t to be that specific.

Comment: how specific is the selector for .wpb_wrapper?  if it's just a single-class selector, .centertext .wpb_wrapper {} might be enough? if you post a link or at least a larger snippet, that would make it a little easier to say exactly how specific you need to be.  It also seems like you may want to look into a preprocessor like https://sass-lang.com/